# Using boolean indexing to filter all rows where the field for one column is contained within the field for another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am relatively new to pandas.  I have a used cars dataset that contains three columns - name, brand, and model.

For example:

```
name                 brand       model
Ford_Fiesta          Ford        Fiesta
Volkswagen_Golf_1.4  Volkswagen  Golf
BMW_316i             BMW         316i
BMW_318i             BMW         318i
Volkswagen_Polo      Volkswagen  Polo
Another_car          Some_Make   Some_Model
```

I'd like something like this:

```
model_in_name = autos["name"].str.contains(autos["model"])
```

Where the boolean indexing for these rows would return the following:

```
True
True
True
True
True
False
```

Here are their value_counts():

```
name
Ford_Fiesta                                                         78
Volkswagen_Golf_1.4                                                 75
BMW_316i                                                            75
BMW_318i                                                            72
Volkswagen_Polo                                                     72
                                                                    ..
Golf_3_GTI_3_Tuerer                                                  1
BMW_320_xDrive_Touring                                               1
Mercedes_Benz_Vito_113_L_Automatik_Klima_Elektrische_Schiebedach     1
Seat_Cordoba_1.6i_SE_mit_neuem_TÜV                                   1
Toyota_Yaris_1.4D_Diesel__KLIMA_S_Linie                              1
Name: name, Length: 38754, dtype: int64

model
golf          4024
andere        3528
3er           2761
polo          1757
corsa         1735
              ... 
kappa            2
200              1
b_max            1
i3               1
rangerover       1
Name: model, Length: 245, dtype: int64

brand
volkswagen        10687
opel               5461
bmw                5429
mercedes_benz      4734
audi               4283
ford               3479
renault            2404
peugeot            1456
fiat               1308
seat                941
skoda               786
mazda               757
nissan              754
smart               701
citroen             701
toyota              617
sonstige_autos      546
hyundai             488
volvo               457
mini                424
mitsubishi          406
honda               399
kia                 356
alfa_romeo          329
porsche             294
suzuki              293
chevrolet           283
chrysler            181
dacia               129
daihatsu            128
jeep                110
subaru              109
land_rover           99
saab                 80
daewoo               79
trabant              78
jaguar               77
rover                69
lancia               57
lada                 31
Name: brand, dtype: int64
```

I don't understand why the dtype for all these columns is int64 if they contain string information, and I question whether this is part of the problem, but I'm not sure how to proceed if it is.  In any case, I have tried several options to return this information:

```
model_in_name = autos["name"].str.contains(autos["model"])
brand_in_name = autos["name"].str.contains(autos["name"])
```

This returns "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed"

```
model_in_name = autos.apply(lambda x: x.model in x.name, axis = 1)
brand_in_name = autos.apply(lambda x: x.brand in x.name, axis = 1)
```

This returns "TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable"

```
model_in_name = autos.apply(lambda x: x['model'] in x['name'], axis = 1)
brand_in_name = autos.apply(lambda x: x['brand'] in x['name'], axis = 1)
```

This returns "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not float"

```
model_in_name = autos["name"].str.contains("|".join(autos["model"]))
brand_in_name = autos["name"].str.contains("|".join(autos["brand"]))
```

This returns "sequence item 10: expected str instance, float found"

I'd really appreciate any insight people could provide about where I'm going wrong.

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 3):

#### Right approach

```
df.apply(lambda x: x['model'] in x['name'], axis=1)
```

#### Cause of the problem:

Notice that you are applying a lambda function along index axis and when you try to access the special attribute `name` using `x.name` this will return the name of the row/series which in this case will be the value of index for that row which is an integer. Hence `x.model` in `some integer` will raise an error.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  After seeing your suggestion I tried this approach but it resulted in another error: "TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not float" (see updated description)

Comment: It might be due to the nan values in `name` column. You can use: `df.apply(lambda x: pd.notna(x['name']) and x['model'] in x['name'], axis=1)`